# After upgrading to Ubuntu 23.10 I am unable to access my Seagate 10TB expansion drive

Tags: usb, mount, external-hdd

I upgraded from 23.04 to 23.10 and everything seemed to go smoothly except that I am now unable to mount my seagate 10TB expansion drive. Sometimes it is not even available but unplugging and replugging fixes that. However, it also shows the Rubbish bin which was not visible before this drive was plugged in.
When I try to mount it I get an error message showing

Unable to access Seagate Expansion Drive
Error mounting /dev/sdb2 at /media/uname/ Seagate Expansion Drive: mount(2) system call failed: No such file or directory
OK

The drive is mounted by Windows 10 OK.
Can you tell me how I can investigate this?

Comment: It might have changed device name from /dev/sdb2 to something else. Try finding it in the output of the `lsblk` command

Comment: check the line /etc/fstab for this device, it will be wrong,